# SyncThing, Lolipop, and "Transport endpoint not connected"

Tags: sync, 5.1-lollipop

I'm trying to get 2 way sync going with Syncthing on OctOS L (Lolipop, based on Cyanogen) with folders on the SD card.  Backup from Android to other Syncthings works fine.  The Syncthing devs say it's complicated to make things work properly on the SD card because of Google, and someone [made a blurb](https://tech.joel-hatsch.net/posts/2015/05/syncthing-and-androids-sd-card/) on it.  Not sure why, but the fix doesn't seem to work for me.

I seem to be running into this issue, and the error I'm getting is weird, but more importantly, I'm not sure what Syncthing is doing to my SD Card.

Once Syncthing tries to write to the SD card, it fails, and then the SD card is unavailable to the rest of the system.  For example, Total Commander.  The only way I can get it back is to reboot the phone.  Using the built in Android tools, I cannot mount the SD card.

What does Syncthing do to the SD card when this happens?  Is it messing with the mount point?

Answer (score -1):

Try different Sd card or your sd card might have a low space try Different method like Syncthing to otg or internal storage.

Comment: Sorry, but this is more of a comment than a proper answer. Just 18 points more, and you can post comments since then. :-)

Comment: No option to add comments without giving answer in Android app stack exchange ohh so i need 18 points thanks for telling.

Comment: Actually, when I commented yu had 32 points, now you have 26, but not to worry. The moment you reach 50 points, you would be able to comment on anyone's post. :-) See [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to know what privileges you can earn with reputation points.

Comment: Ok thank you very much @firelord you comment on all my four answers .

Comment: Please keep up the good work of answering. If you need help, visit our [help], [meta] or [chat]. :-)

Comment: Thanks @firelord im improving my knowledge and learning lot of stuff from this site and i will answering as much i know again thanking you for helping me.